# r dplyr and data.table: aggregate then join back to original table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I frequently find myself calculating summary statistics of data frames using the following **dplyr** syntax:

```
1. Aggregate <- 
2. Original Dataset %>%
3. Group_By %>%
4. Filter %>% 
5. Summarize %>%
6. Left_Join(back to Aggregate)
```

For example:

```
Original <- data.frame(A = 1:100,B = sample(LETTERS,100,replace = TRUE),C = rnorm(100))

# Calculate 1st Summary Statistic
Aggregate <- Original %>% group_by(B) %>% 
             filter(A > 50) %>% 
             summarize(meanC = mean(C))

# Calculate 2nd Summary Statistic
Aggregate <- Original %>% group_by(B) %>% 
             summarize(Q = sum(C)) %>%
             left_join(x = Aggregate,y = Original,by = "B")
```

My question is two fold:

A) Is there a better way of building a table of summary statistics off another table?  The left-join feels very clunky.

B) What is the "data.table" way of doing this, i.e., how do I join back to the Aggregate table?

```
Aggregate[Aggregate[,meanC:=mean(C),by=.(B)]]
```

Thanks for any advice...

Comment: In data.table, no need for the merge, just `orig[ , meanC := mean(C), by=B]`

Comment: @DanY Thanks Dan for the comment.  That's good to know.  In this case, how would I calculate the Aggregate table, which only has 26 rows, one row for each Group?

Comment: I guess the deal is I keep running into situations where I want to compute multiple summaries of large amounts of data by 1 row, i.e. the aggregation...

Comment: `agg <- orig[ , .(meanC = mean(C)), by=B]`  See [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Comment: Right....so I can do that once, but say I have like a 100 different summaries to compute, instead of doing it all in one line, how do I break it up into multiple column additions to the same summary table...hence the join

Comment: In your example, the first `Aggregate` table has a filter statement but the second one does not, is that a typo? If not do you really want to join summary columns in the same df where each summary has different conditions associated with it?

Comment: @Mike Oddly enough, I do find myself calculating summary statistics which sometimes involve filtering, sometimes not, for the same aggregated table.  Not sure if that's unusual...

Comment: I would say in general if you are presenting the results to  people I would consider keeping the tables separate and describing each table clearly. It will probably help you out in the long run and it will be clearer for the audience. If it is just for you I would comment aggressively just to be aware what each column stands for.

Comment: For multiple summaries at the same time with data.table, look into `':='()` notation as well as `lapply` with `.SDcols`.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the join if you mutate after the group_by instead of summarize.

```
library(tidyverse)
Original <- data.frame(A = 1:100,B = sample(LETTERS,100,replace = TRUE),C = rnorm(100))

# Calculate unfiltered summary statistic, as in OP
Aggregate_OP <- Original %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  summarize(meanC = mean(C)) %>% 
  right_join(Original) %>% 
  select(A, B, C, meanC) # reorder columns
#> Joining, by = "B"

# Simpler, using mutate
Aggregate_mutate <- Original %>% 
  group_by(B) %>% 
  mutate(meanC = mean(C)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# with dplyr 1.1.0+, we can do:
Aggregate_mutate <- Original %>% 
  mutate(meanC = mean(C), .by = B)


identical(Aggregate_OP |> arrange(A), tibble(Aggregate_mutate))
#> [1] TRUE
```

UPDATE -- to calculate a filtered stat like in the OP:

```
Original %>% 
  mutate(meanC = mean(C[A > 50]), .by = B)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe DanY pointed most of this out in the comments but posting for completeness sake. You don't really need to do any merging w/ `data.table`:

```r
# data
Original <- data.frame(A = 1:100, B = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE), C = rnorm(100))

# to data.table
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(Original)

# first summary
dt[A > 50, meanC := mean(C)]

# second summary
dt[, Q := sum(C), by = B]
```

Though if you did want to save off those table, you certainly can:

```
# to data.table
dt <- data.table::as.data.table(Original)

# first aggreggate
agg_a <- dt[A > 50, .(A, meanC = mean(C))]

# second aggregate
agg_b <- dt[, .(Q = sum(C)), by = B]

# merge
dt <- data.table::merge.data.table(dt, agg_a, by = "A", all.x = TRUE)
dt <- data.table::merge.data.table(dt, agg_b, by = "B", all.x = TRUE)
```